# How to plot a probability distribution with `pymc.MCMC` in Python

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, pymc, mcmc

I know that I can use:

```
S = pymc.MCMC(model1)
from pymc import Matplot as mcplt
mcplt.plot(S)
```

and that will give me a figure with three plots but all I want is just a single plot of the histogram. Then I want to normalise the histogram and then make a plot a smooth curve of the distribution rather than the bars of the histogram. Could anyone help me to code this so I can get a final plot of the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `matplotlib` installed for plotting, and `scipy` for doing a kernel density estimate ([many KDE functions exist](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/)), then you could do something similar to the following (based on [this example](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/tutorial.html#fitting-the-model-with-mcmc), where `'late_mean'` is one of the names of the sampled parameters in that case):

```
from pymc.examples import disaster_model
from pymc import MCMC
import numpy as np

M = MCMC(disaster_model) # you could substitute your own model

# perform sampling of model
M.sample(iter=10000, burn=1000, thin=10)

# get numpy array containing the MCMC chain of the parameter you want: 'late_mean' in this case
chain = M.trace('late_mean')[:]

# import matplotlib plotting functions
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl

# plot histogram (using 15 bins, but you can choose whatever you want) - density=True returns a normalised histogram
pl.hist(chain, bins=15, histtype='stepfilled', density=True)
ax = pl.gca() # get current axis

# import scipy gaussian KDE function
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# create KDE of samples
kde = gaussian_kde(chain)

# calculate KDE at a range of points (in this case based on the current plot, but you could choose a range based on the chain)
vals = np.linspace(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_xlim()[1], 100)

# overplot KDE
pl.plot(vals, kde(vals), 'b')

pl.xlabel('late mean')
pl.ylabel('PDF')

# show the plot
pl.show()

# save the plot
pl.savefig('hist.png', dpi=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I believe [`arviz.plot_kde()`](https://python.arviz.org/en/stable/examples/plot_kde.html) is the way forward. Quoting the example directly from the docs page:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import arviz as az

az.style.use("arviz-doc")

data = az.load_arviz_data("centered_eight")

# Combine posterior draws for from xarray of (4,500) to ndarray (2000,)
y_hat = np.concatenate(data.posterior_predictive["obs"].values)

az.plot_kde(
    y_hat,
    label="Estimated Effect\n of SAT Prep",
    rug=True,
    plot_kwargs={"linewidth": 2},
    rug_kwargs={"alpha": 0.05},
)

plt.show()
```